# ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends - boxsdk on Mac

Tags: python, macos, openssl, cryptography

I'm currently trying to automate the upload of a single file (for now) to Box from my Python automation.

I'm using the code from the Box developers website that is supposed to be "super easy to use" but I am getting an error (see title above) when I try to run the simple program found on this page: https://www.box.com/blog/introducing-box-python-sdk/ . I've added my client ID, client secret, and developer token, and added the path to my zip file to upload, and keep getting the above error. I havent changed anything beyond that.

Code for those who dont want to click into the link :)

```
from boxsdk import Client, OAuth2

oauth = OAuth2(
    client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    client_secret="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
    access_token="YOUR_DEVELOPER_TOKEN",
)

client = Client(oauth)
shared_folder = client.folder(
    folder_id='0',
).create_subfolder('shared_folder')

uploaded_file = shared_folder.upload('/path/to/file')
shared_link = shared_folder.get_shared_link()
```

I've installed the cryptography program using pip AND easy_install just to be sure, along with libffi and openssl and oauth2 just to be safe and nothing works. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: I've voted up in the hope that this is some kind of generic issue. But note that it is pretty hard to debug runtime configurations that happen on your PC, so I would not bet too much on getting an answer here. Good luck!

Answer (score 24):

This error has nothing to do with the `boxsdk` library but with one of its dependency: `cryptography`.

Most of the time, it happens because the `cryptography` library install failed. Most of the time, it failed because libffi is not installed by default on most computers.

If you're using brew, just go in your terminal and type `brew install libffi`

Then reinstall `cryptography` or `boxsdk` with `pip`:

`pip install cryptography --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 14):

Try this out. Good luck!

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/fabric-home-assistant

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev

sudo pip install cryptography --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same error when trying to run paramiko on AWS Lambda, which depends on pycrypto. I fixed it by running the following before I did the pip install for each:

```
sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
```

This seemed to work because the pip install of pycrypto was looking for headers which it could not find.

Comment: This is similar to the issues that I was running into.  I installed the above-listed packages and followed this blog post:  aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/