# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography' - Unable to recognize cryptography

Tags: python, pip, python-idle, python-cryptography

I've installed and reinstalled Python 3 (using version 3.7.9) as well as pip and cryptography via the command prompt with success (message below):

> Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (3.4.7)

However, python is unable to recognize Cryptography and continues to give the same error message (below) each time I try and run a python script that is using cryptography to download packages.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

For whatever reason, python is unable to recognize that Cryptography is installed, or at least seems to be installed.

Is there any other way I can test or look for errors?

Does it take a certain amount of time after being installed before python can recognize cyptographgy (I've only just installed it an hour ago)?

I'll keep trying and re-attempting to find a solution, but if you've seen this before or know a solutions, please let me know.

The program I'm using is IDLE to run the scripts.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: In IDLE, type `help("modules")`, and see if the name `cryptography` is present in the list

Comment: Also, try checking out this advice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135481/11634814